# export animation to fbx or md2

Tags: animation, export, bezier-curves

I've been using blender to export models and simple animations into an augmented reality environment, but I'm starting to run into exporting issues.

Specifically, I'm trying to animate a wire plugging into a connector.  My setup is a cylinder with a curve modifier, with a few hooks that have bones attached to them.  The animation itself looks great, but when I try to export, the cylinder doesn't move (the connector on the end of it, which is a separate object, moves fine).

I suspect that it has something to do with the modifier getting applied, or not applied during export.  I also tried using shape keys, but they don't like to play along with the curve modifier.

I can export to md2 or fbx.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second read, I think I understand better. You are exporting a mesh with a modifier to an engine that doesn't support the same modifiers. Most realtime engines only support bone animations - a lot of them don't even support shape keys. 
Basically, you can't do what you are doing :)

You have a couple of options:

1: animate it in a way that doesn't use curve modifiers, only bones (might not be easy though)

2: save your mesh animation as an MDD (mesh cache) and load that into your engine, if possible.

3: See if you can set up an equivalent to a curve modifier in your engine. For example, you might be able to make a script that makes the wire traverse through a series of null points. This depends on the engine you are using though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if this button is enabled in the modifier?

[image: did you check if this is on]