# When I export to fbx and then import animation of moving track animation doesnt work

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, .fbx

i think that this is banal problem, but i tried to find a solution for few hours and I wasnt successfull.
I tried to copy this yt tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiG4--fKVps.
And export this blend file [image]
with animation into fbx and after import fbx. And after import no animation is visible.
After successfull export I want import it into Unity3d.
Thank you for help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23439/export-animation-to-fbx-or-md2?rq=1 (Blender modifiers can't be exported to FBX or any other format.)

Comment: but abc (alembic) worked

Comment: Yep. forgot about that one but you did specifically say FBX! :^)